# What mail software allows archiving (rather than deleting) like in Gmail?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, email, mail, sylpheed

It appears that [Sylpheed, the default mail software for Lubuntu 18.04, deletes mail rather than archiving it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085332/how-do-i-archive-mail-in-sylpheed-3-5-1), but I am still trying to verify that I'm not overlooking some hidden option.

What software should I use to archive mail rather than delete it? I also wish to view multiple accounts' mail together, rather than clicking mailbox by mailbox. Basically, I like macOS's Mail application, which enables users to view mail separately or collectively, and to archive or delete.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Thunderbird is one package that will let you archive mail (See: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages).

You can also combine messages from different POP accounts in a global inbox (See: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unify-your-pop-email-accounts-global-inbox).